# Unset/Change Binding in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

How can I unset the binding applied to an object so that I can apply another binding to it from a different location?

Suppose I have two data templates binded to the **same object reference**.

Data Template #1 is the default template to be loaded. I try to bind a button command to a `Function1` from my DataContext class:

```
<Button Content="Button 1" CommandParameter="{Binding }" Command="{Binding DataContext.Function1, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```

This actually works and the function gets binded. However, when I try to load Data Template # 2 to the same object (while trying to bind another button command to a different function (`Function2`) from my DataContext class):

```
<Button Content="Button 2" CommandParameter="{Binding }" Command="{Binding DataContext.Function2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

It doesn't work and the first binding is still the one executed. Is there a workaround to this?

**EDIT (for better problem context):**

I defined my templates in my Window.Resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel1}">
        <local:View1 />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel2}">
        <local:View2 />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

The View1.xaml and the View2.xaml contain the button definitions that I described above (I want them to command the control of my process flow).
ViewModel1 and ViewModel2 are my ViewModels that implement the interface `IPageViewModel` which is the type of my variable `CurrentPageViewModel`.

In my XAML, I binded `ContentControl` to the variable `CurrentPageViewModel`:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

In my .CS, I have a list defined as `List<IPageViewModel> PageViewModels`, which I use to contain the instances of my two View Models:

```
PageViewModels.Add(new ViewModel1());
PageViewModels.Add(new ViewModel2());

// Set starting page
CurrentPageViewModel = PageViewModels[0];
```

When I try to change my `CurrentPageViewModel` to the other view model, this is when I want the new binding to work. Unfortunately, it doesn't. Am I doing things the right way?

Comment: Are these buttons part of the DataTemplate? How are you setting the DataTemplate? By Name? Implicit? Is there a condition that applies when to use which function? Can't you just use 2 different templates?

Comment: How are you switching between the DataTempates? Depending on that, you could call [CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested.aspx) to update the bindings straight after.

Comment: @keyboardP InvalidateRequerySuggested doesn't update bindings, it is only to tell the command system "Check again if commands can be executed" It just reevaluates the CanExecute of commands.

Comment: Provide complete reproducible example, please.

Comment: @dowhilefor Sorry, I should rephrase that. It updates the commands by reevaluating, as you say, the CanExecute. I've seen it suggested before as a workaround to updating commands although not a nice solution.

Comment: Yes, the buttons are inside the DataTemplates. The templates are explicitly declared in my Windows Resources as two different templates with types implementing the interface of the object that they are binded to. In my .cs file, I want my interface reference to interchange between the different views (that correspond to the templates) and the buttons serve as my control in each of them.

Comment: @captcalamares the question still stands. Why can't you use a different DataTemplate for both functions? just create 2 DataTemplates func1Template and func2Template and assign them when necessary.

Comment: Now that i see your update: Are you raising CurrentPageViewModel? is it a dependency property? Or are you implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: @dowhilefor I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged for CurrentPageViewModel.

Comment: Sorry i have to nitpick, because thats a very common mistake. You don't implement INotifyPropertyChanged for a property, you implement it for a class, and then you need to call the event in every setter of every view bound property to make the ui aware of changes of that particular property. So in short does your CurrentPageViewModel setter contains a call to the PropertyChanged event?

Comment: @dowhilefor Yes, that is what i meant, sorry for the confusion :)) I am currently trying your TemplateSelector approach if that can do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you are unable to use just two different DataTemplates, usually because the datatemplates are very large or complex, i suggest using `ContentControl` and `DataTemplateSelector`.

In your DataTemplates place another `ContentControl`, create 2 DataTemplates just containing your button, one with Function1 one with Function2. Create a `DataTemplateSelector` and set it on the initial ContentControl. The `DataTemplateSelector` now just need to select the proper template depending on a decision, for example the type of the item or a property on the item etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to unset binding you can do it from code like:
    `BindingOperations.ClearBinding(txtName, TextBox.TextProperty)`

But TemplateSelector approach will be more efficient.

Comment: I actually tried this solution but how can I convert my object argument to a System.Window.DependencyObject? I tried casting but it doesn't work.